# Firebase rendering a custom page on 404

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

I am using Firebase Hosting for my site and if someone tries a direct link like my.site/contact they see a standard 404 rendered by firebase.

I want to replace it with my own page and hence I created a page with name 404.html and placed in `src/` as well as `src/app/`

However, this does not work. My `firebase.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

The another option I can live with is directing people to login page. I guess that would need to add a routing rule to `firebase.json` .

Comment: Make sure your 404.html page is in the same page as your index.html... You said your site shows Firebase's default 404 page. That means you have their 404.html file in your project's directory. You should search for it and replace with your own

Answer (score 1):

Please read the [documentation for Custom 404/Not Found page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/url-redirects-rewrites#section-404).

Your `404.html` file must be at the very top level of the public content directory, which by your configuration looks like it would be `dist`.

Comment: you are correct here. however, on doing ng serve dist gets created with no 404.html and when i do a firebase deploy then firebase upload this and deletes the directory. so basically solution works by copying manually but it is a pain

Comment: You could write a script that does everything in one command.

Comment: yeah seems just a overhead to do such a simple thing of taking care of 404 page

Comment: Maybe you should ask a second question to find out if there is a right way to do this. The firebase tools won't help you.

Comment: This would be a question for the Angular tooling -- something like "How can I specify additional files to copy into `dist`?"